# In firefox, how can I run javascript in local file e.g., file:///C:/play/my.html

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, content-security-policy

I wanted to experiment with Javascript and created a file that I opened in Firefox (68.0.1) `file:///C:/play/my.html`.  The file is on JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/PatS2265/7r4j6ewa/ (but the code works in JSFiddle).

In Firefox when I opened this file I got the following error in the console:

**Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).**

I looked up how to fix this and tried adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">
```

but this didn't fix it.  The file is shown below (with my failed attempt at adding the Content-Security-Policy meta tag.

**What is the correct syntax for the Content-Security-Policy?**

**NOTE: In Chrome (v76.0.3809.100), this file just worked so that my work around for now.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Async Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
function clickMe() {
  f().then(alert);
}
async function f() {
  return 1;
}
</script>
  Just testing
  <button type="button" onclick="clickMe()">Run Async Function</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**Searches**

I did a search for how to fix this and came across a solution to disable the Content-Security-Policy.

- [Disabling Content Security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324485/3281336) in Firefox.  This worked for me but is pretty heavy handed, so I'd like to know how to do it in my file.

Other results that were helpful were:

- [How to use Content-Security-Policy with localhost files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081328/how-to-use-content-security-policy-with-localhost-files)
- [The MDN docs for the Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy)
- [How to use Content-Security-Policy with localhost files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081328/how-to-use-content-security-policy-with-localhost-files)
- [How can I read local files from JavaScript with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894714/how-can-i-read-local-files-from-javascript-with-firefox)

I just found tag in StackOverflow for content-security-policy so I'll start that search now.

Comment: Just run a local server

Comment: That's not an option.  I can't install any software on work machine and it doesn't have python or node, or other development apps that I would typically use on my development box.  I typically use https://codesandbox.io but ran into a problem which I've since fixed.  See https://df35m.csb.app/.  I was curious why this didn't just work in Firefox!

Comment: You can't run node or python?

Comment: @epascarello, I updated my previous comment to address this suggestion.

Comment: Interesting, when I view my solution in CodeSandBox.io, I also see errors like `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://codesandbox.io/static/js/sandbox.9b5dc6d7.js (“script-src”).`, but the script does still work, whereas when I load the file locally it does not work.

Comment: Works fine in my Firefox, do you have any add-ons by chance? Did you try in a clean profile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I feel a little bit embarrassed that I didn't get this sooner.
I have to credit @Nickolay for commenting that he did not see this problem and asked if it could be an AddOn, or if I had tried this in a new profile, so I checked both.

I created a clean profile using `about:profiles` and clicking on `Create a New Profile`, and when I ran in that profile it worked!

Next I realized that I had the Add-On **NoScript** enabled which was preventing Javascript from running on the on the local files (`file:///C:/`)!

After I enabled local files in **NoScript** the problem went away.
Doh (hand hitting forehead).